# .htaccess change parameters received directly after domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have been looking for many tutorials bu no one has really helped me, I know you guys can:
My website has the following structure:

*mywebsite.domain/?pg=somepage*

But I would like to leave it like this:

*mywebsite.domain/somepage*

All the tutorials I have found work in the next structure:
*mywebsite.domain/file.php?pg=somepage*
So I can't gess how a RewriteRule would be using my structure.

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php/?pg=$1
```

And also:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?pg=$1
```

But I have had no luck :(
**Note:** My index file has .php extension

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect `mywebsite.domain/somepage` to `mywebsite.domain/index.php?pg=somepage`

or full config -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pg=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

for more info - [Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I tested it but now I get error 500

Comment: I edited the answer try this one  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pg=$1 [PT]`